# Double summation in function which will be used for log likelihood estimation

Tags: r, function, loops, optimization, sum

I am trying to get the estimation parameters for the following equation:

[image]

First, I need to write the function with double summation. Then, I will use any optimization method to get the estimated parameters (can be nlm, optim etc). Here is my attempt (though, I am not sure how to add the double summation part in the end, two for loops):

There are 5 parameters: alpha_x, sigma_x, lambda_x, theta_x, phi_x >>> `step_3[1] == alpha_x`

```
for (a in 1:nrow(returns[[4]][,1])){
      abc <- 0      
for (b in 0:7){
  abc <- abc + (step_3[3]^b*(factorial(b))^-1*(sqrt(step_3[2]^2+b*step_3[5]^2))^-1*exp(-1*(as.numeric(returns[[4]][a,1])-(step_3[1]+b*step_3[4]))^2*(2*(step_3[2]^2+b*step_3[5]^2))^-1))
}
      abcd  <- abcd + log(abc)
    } 
  abcd <- -abcd  + 0.5*nrow(returns[[4]][,1])*log(2*pi) + nrow(returns[[4]][,1])*step_3[3]

  return(abcd)
  }

nlm(s3, step_3 <- c(0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01), hessian = TRUE )
```

I am getting the estimation results, but the estimates are way off:

My question is how to implement (efficiently, any suggestions for sapply etc. would be appreciated) **the double summation (sum_0_T) > ln (sum_1_l) into a function.** The function will be used in optimization. 
(l=0:7, T=number of observations)
return[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO068.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO068.png) = some vector with price returns (all returns between -1,1). 
After the estimation sample mean and variance should be roughly equal to:

sample_mean = alpha_x + lambda_x * theta_x

sample_variance = sigma_x^2 + lambda_x * (theta_x^2 + phi_x^2)

Thanks.

Here is a sample that can be used for the analysis:

c(0.02423747 ,-0.00419738, -0.03153278, 0.05343888, -0.0175492, 0.00848472, 0.01043673, -0.02123556, 0.01954968, -0.06462473, 0.02679873, 0.07971938, 0.00050474, -0.01768566,
  -0.05206762, -0.00413691, 0.06390499, 0.00269576, 0.01520837, 0.00091051, 0.03499043, -0.00121999, -0.00123521, -0.01961684, 0.03360355, 0.01803711, 0.01772631, 0.036523
  -0.00038927, 0.00905013, 0.01150976, 0.00480223, 0.01916402, 0.00054628, 0.01911904, 0.02194556, 0.00371314, 0.03376601, 0.0546574, -0.03972611, -0.0272525, 0.00271509,
  0.02137819, 0.00483075, 0.03538795, 0.02981431, 0.00428509, -0.07192935, 0.01770175, -0.09626522, 0.07574215, 0.02929555, 0.01776551, 0.0385604, -0.06804089, 0.0666583,
  0.01304272, -0.01825728, 0.01703525, 0.02022584, 0.03348027, 0.02818876, -0.00162942, -0.08785954, -0.13366772, 0.10243928)